# Camera2 API Android min SDK

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

Hello I am trying to develop an application that uses a custom Camera, when I try to use the Camera class it was deprecated so I have used android hardware. Camera 2 and followed this  [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024223336/https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/)

but when I try to add CameraDevice.StatecCallBack it gives me a warning that the min SDK should be 21 and my min SDK is 15
Now I'm confused if I used the old Camera API its deprecated if i used the new one it doesn't support my min SDK what should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

"Deprecated" in Android usually means "we have something else that you should consider using". Deprecated classes and methods usually still work, and on older Android devices often times you have no choice but to use them.

So, your options are:

1. Use `android.hardware.Camera` all the time, or
2. Use `android.hardware.Camera` for devices running older than API Level 21, then use `android.hardware.camera2.*` for devices running API Level 21+